# Use Chrome prediction result service with Custom Search Engine

Tags: google-chrome, search-engine

If I change my search engine to a custom one in Chrome, chrome URL prediction service stops completely even if I've enabled `Use a prediction service to help complete searches and URLs typed in the address bar or the app launcher search box`. It only works with default search engine like Google, Bing, Yahoo. How can I make it work with my custom search engine?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer (thanks to [Labnol](http://www.labnol.org/internet/google-autocomplete/20434/)). Chrome and other new browsers are using Open Search Standard which can be used to provide more details to Web Browsers by Search Engines.

To add a new Search Engine, add this code onto your webpage.

```
<a href="javascript:onClick=window.external.AddSearchProvider('search.xml');" target="_self">Add Custom Search</a>
```

And in `search.xml`, add this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" xmlns:moz="http://www.mozilla.org/2006/browser/search/">  
<ShortName>SE</ShortName>
<Description>Search using SE</Description>
<InputEncoding>UTF-8</InputEncoding>
<Url type="application/x-suggestions+json" method="GET" template="https://www.google.com/complete/search?client=chrome-omni&amp;gs_ri=chrome-ext-ansg&amp;xssi=t&amp;q={searchTerms}"/>
<Url type="text/html" method="GET" template="http://localhost/search?q={searchTerms}"/>
<SearchForm>http://localhost/</SearchForm>
</OpenSearchDescription>
```

See [this](http://www.opensearch.org/Specifications/OpenSearch/1.1) for more information on the standard.